# Ошибка смены layout-ов с фрагментами после изменения ориентации экрана устройства

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-layout

### Описание задачи

Есть одно Activity на котором размещаются компоненты:
0. Два *RelativeLayout*, на которых расположено по одной Button и TextView. При нажатии на кнопку генерится случайное число и заносится в TextView (fragment_tab_one.xml и fragment_tab_two.xml).

1. В вертикальном положении (layout/activity_main.xml):

   - *TabLayout* с двумя вкладками и этими фрагментами
   - *ViewPager* для перелистывания этих вкладок и смены фрагментов.
   - *FragmentPagerAdapter*
2. В горизонтальном положении (layout/land/activity_main.xml):

   - Два *FrameLayout* в котором должны находиться эти фрагменты при изменении ориентации девайса.

#### Необходимо

При запуске приложения сгенерить по случайному числу на каждой вкладке и при повороте экрана не потерять эти данные во **фрагментах**.

### Проблема

При повороте дисплея приложение завершается с ошибкой следующего характера.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment TabOneFragment{428ecb60 #0 id=0x7f0c006a android:switcher:2131492970:0}: was 2131492970 now 2131492972
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:427)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:449)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:441)
at innovatecode.com.tabexample.MainActivity.setUpLandscapeLayout(MainActivity.java:60)
at innovatecode.com.tabexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Честно, перепробовал вроде бы все что можно, но ничего не помогает. Может реально где-то туплю, т.к. с фрагментами только начал работать.  Полностью проект находится на [гугл диске](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MVbIYaF0RW_DtU-SEqnxmpvBKiTVnRNC). Если можете, пожалуйста, посмотрите этот проект, он не большой. Т.к. реально нескем проконсультироваться и очень тяжело увидеть свою ошибку.

И класс главной активности на которой я остановился:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Fragment tabOneFragment;
    private Fragment tabTwoFragment;

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //Restore the fragment's instance
            tabOneFragment = (TabOneFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                    savedInstanceState, "tabOneFragment");
            tabTwoFragment = (TabTwoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                    savedInstanceState, "tabTwoFragment");
        } else {
            tabOneFragment = new TabOneFragment();
            tabTwoFragment = new TabTwoFragment();
        }

        if (findViewById(R.id.tab_layout) != null) {
            setUpPortraitLayout();
        } else {
            setUpLandscapeLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "tabOneFragment", tabOneFragment);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "tabTwoFragment", tabTwoFragment);
    }

    private void setUpPortraitLayout() {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Assign created adapter to viewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        // This method setup all required method for TabLayout with Viewpager
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setUpLandscapeLayout() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_left, tabOneFragment);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_right, tabTwoFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        // As we are implementing two tabs
        private static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        // For each tab different fragment is returned
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return tabOneFragment;

                case 1:
                    return tabTwoFragment;

                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid tab index");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() { return NUM_ITEMS; }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {  return "Tab " + (position + 1); }

    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72030/discussion-on-question-by-tomas---layout-----).